# Firebase not picking up index file from index folder

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have added 2 folders in public

1- a folder named 'index' contains index.html.

2- a folder named 'about contains index.html.

I've hosted these 2 folders on firebase but firebase isn't picking index.html from index folder, but if I paste directly in root it picks it up, why is this so? I also want to add one thing more that linking to just 'about' folder it automatically picks index.html file from about folder whenever I want to navigate from index to about.

I want to achieve this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

Comment: Could you give more detail on what you exactly want to achieve. What do you mean by "firebase isn't picking xxx.html"? Sorry but it is not crystal clear for the moment.

Comment: like when we are hosting on firebase we just add index.html and related linked files and firebase picks up index.html as home page. but i want that instead directly adding index.html in public firebase picks up index.html from index folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one or more **rewrites** and/or **redirects**, see the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites

For example, the following `firebase.json` file would work:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",

    "redirects": [ {
      "source" : "/contact",
      "destination" : "/contact/contact.html",
      "type" : 301
    } ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index/index.html"
      }
    ],

    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that instead of "a folder named about contains index.html" we use in the above config a folder named `contact` which contains a `contact.html` file.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can guide a bit more for this case.

Comment: Done @RenaudTarnec